# Android: Inserting space in an edittext causes a crash

Tags: java, android, json, url, uri

My edit text serves as a search box, and I am getting movies from rotten tomatoes API, using the text inside my edit text, problem is. when a space is inserted the application crashes, I am assuming that I need to convert the spaces into +'s, but I have no clue how where to add this code or how exactly, I hope someone here will be able to help me.

this is my code:

```
    private TextView searchBox;
    private Button bGo, bCancelAddFromWeb;
    private ListView moviesList;
    public final static int ACTIVITY_WEB_ADD = 3;

    public List<String> movieTitles;
    public List<String> movieSynopsis;
    public List<String> movieImgUrl;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // the Rotten Tomatoes API key
    private static final String API_KEY = "8q6wh77s65a54w433cab9rbsq";

    // the number of movies to show
    private static final int MOVIE_PAGE_LIMIT = 8;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movie_add_from_web);

        InitializeVariables();

    }

    /*
     * Initializing the variables and creating the bridge between the views from
     * the xml file and this class
     */

    private void InitializeVariables() {

        searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchBox);
        bGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGo);
        bCancelAddFromWeb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancelAddFromWeb);
        moviesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_movies);

        bGo.setOnClickListener(this);
        bCancelAddFromWeb.setOnClickListener(this);
        moviesList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bGo:
            new RequestTask()
                    .execute("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey="
                            + API_KEY
                            + "&q="
                            + searchBox.getText()
                            + "&page_limit=" + MOVIE_PAGE_LIMIT);
            break;

        case R.id.bCancelAddFromWeb:
            finish();
            break;

        }

    }

    private void refreshMoviesList(List<String> movieTitles) {
        moviesList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, movieTitles
                        .toArray(new String[movieTitles.size()])));
    }

    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // make a request to the specified url
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                // make a HTTP request
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                } else {
                    // close connection
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Test", "Couldn't make a successful request!");
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        // if the request above completed successfully, this method will
        // automatically run so you can do something with the response

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MovieAddFromWeb.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Searching...");
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);

            try {
                // convert the String response to a JSON object
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                // fetch the array of movies in the response
                JSONArray jArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("movies");

                // add each movie's title to a list
                movieTitles = new ArrayList<String>();

                // newly added
                movieSynopsis = new ArrayList<String>();
                movieImgUrl = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject movie = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    movieTitles.add(movie.getString("title"));

                    movieSynopsis.add(movie.getString("synopsis"));
                    movieImgUrl.add(movie.getJSONObject("posters").getString(
                            "profile"));

                }
                // refresh the ListView
                refreshMoviesList(movieTitles);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("Test", "Couldn't successfully parse the JSON response!");
            }
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent openMovieEditor = new Intent(this, MovieEditor.class);
        openMovieEditor.putExtra("movieTitle", movieTitles.get(position));

        // newly added
        openMovieEditor.putExtra("movieSynopsis", movieSynopsis.get(position));
        openMovieEditor.putExtra("movieImgUrl", movieImgUrl.get(position));

        openMovieEditor.putExtra("callingActivity", ACTIVITY_WEB_ADD);
        startActivityForResult(openMovieEditor, ACTIVITY_WEB_ADD);

    }
}
```

this is the log with the error:

```
01-14 20:19:19.591: D/Test(907): Couldn't make a successful request!
01-14 20:19:19.690: D/AndroidRuntime(907): Shutting down VM
01-14 20:19:19.700: W/dalvikvm(907): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at il.jb.projectpart2.MovieAddFromWeb$RequestTask.onPostExecute(MovieAddFromWeb.java:152)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at il.jb.projectpart2.MovieAddFromWeb$RequestTask.onPostExecute(MovieAddFromWeb.java:1)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-14 20:19:19.801: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your LogCat errors so we don't have to guess please.

Comment: Ive added it to my question.

Comment: The NPE is coming from the JSON results, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use standard URL encoding as follows:

```
case R.id.bGo:
    new RequestTask()
            .execute("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey="
                    + API_KEY
                    + "&q="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(searchBox.getText(), "UTF-8")
                    + "&page_limit=" + MOVIE_PAGE_LIMIT);
```

This will replace spaces and all other non-URL-friendly characters with allowed characters (as defined by RFC 1738 and the HTML spec)

Comment: Note that `URLEncoder.encode(String string)` has been depricated since API version 1. It's not a big deal, but _technically_ you should probably use `URLEncoder.encode(searchBox.getText(), "UTF-8")`

Comment: Thank you for answering, I tried using you're updated version with zyklon's tip, but that is what I am getting... the method encode is not applicable for the type (charSequence, string)

Comment: Might have to do `URLEncoder.encode(searchBox.getText().toString(), "UTF-8")`

Comment: yes, eclipse marks the ".encode" in red, and forced me to either cast this to string, which by the way doesn't help, or remove the string "searchbox.gettext()"

Comment: zyklon, you're solution did work, after I surrounded it with try and catch.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your logcat to make sure that's the actual problem, but from your code it looks like it is at least one of your issues.

Ideally you'd do something like

```
String search = searchBox.getText();
search = search.replace(" ", "+");
```

and then use that variable to send to your `RequestTask`

Source: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Conversely, you may be better off doing a full encoding on the string returned instead of just replacing spaces... as other characters will cause you issues as well (?, &, etc)

EDIT: See EJK's answer for the URLEncoding version.